# How can I edit Address Book distribution lists?

Tags: macos, contacts

In Snow Leopard there was a way to select which address to use for each contact in a group, for sending group emails or printing address lists. This was done by selecting the group in the groups column and choosing **Edit** → **Edit Distribution List…**

In the (horrible) Lion Address Book, the feature is still in the Edit menu, but I can't figure out why it's always dimmed. What are the circumstances when this menu item should become available, or how can I choose the addresses for my contact groups in Lion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only local groups (appearing in On My Mac) support distribution lists. This feature won't work if you're only using Exchange, a CardDAV server, or iCloud.

Here's a cnet article about this, with regard to iCloud: http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-20126108-263/address-book-distribution-list-editor-disabled-by-icloud/

Comment: That is a serious drag.  Address Book is getting worse and worse.